# Adaptive visualforce for desktop and mobile

Tags: visualforce, mobile, jquerymobile

What is the best option to implement visualforce page with view for desktop and mobile at the same place. Can this be handled automatically with modern  javascript frameworks like backbone.js, angular.js, etc. For example there is Vf page and this page automatically calculates which view template to use(mobile or desktop), which model to use(mobile and desktop). Actually the mobile and desktop content and behaviour are the same but ui will be reorganized responsively within mobile.

Answer (score 3):

Simple VisualForce pages render reasonably well in Salesforce1 as they are, but if this is general viewing via browser you'll probably find things aren't looking great. If I was going to do this I'd use [Bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com) - it's designed for creating responsive pages easily and wouldn't have an overhead as large as other frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

In the case that you are inside the Salesforce1 Mobile App, you can use the 'sforce' Javascript object to identify mobile vs desktop:

```
// Do something in inside the Salesforce1 Mobile App
if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce != null) ) {
  // Salesforce1 navigation
  sforce.one.navigateToSObject(aId);
}
else {
  // Set the window's URL to the Visualforce page for use on Desktop
  window.location.href = '{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, account.
Id)}';
```

*Note: This will be present if you navigate to /one/one.app, whether that be the Salesforce1 mobile app, in your mobile browser, or a desktop/laptop browser navigated to /one/one.app

You can also use Apex to identify the user agent

```
 global static Boolean isMobile() {
      String device = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('device');
      return (device == 'mobile');
    }
```